# Jira-Trigger plugin is not triggering jenkins job with JQL filter

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-jira-trigger

I am not able to trigger a jenkins build from jira if the jenkins job has a JQL filter.

I have setup the JIRA Trigger configuration.

If I leave the the JQL filter empty, then the job is being triggered. As soon as I put something on the JQL filed in jenkins, then something is wrong. eg JQL filer (project=ProjectName)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a JIRA Trigger configuration issue. I used the wrong username.